# Prove that there are at least 50% of numbers $b$ which satisfy ${b_0}^{n-1} \not \equiv {1} \mod{n}$ if one such $b_0$ exists .

Tags: number-theory, primality-test

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accuracy of Fermat's Little Theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135839/accuracy-of-fermats-little-theorem)

$n$ is odd and composite number,and there exists $b_0$ , $0<b_0<n$ such that $gcd(n,b_0)=1$ and ${b_0}^{n-1} \not \equiv {1} \mod{n}$

**prove** that there are at least 50% of numbers $b$ such that $0<b<n$ and $gcd(b,n)=1$ which satisfy ${b_0}^{n-1} \not \equiv {1} \mod{n}$

Comment: (Note that the assumption that $n$ is composite is redundant, since $b_0^{n-1}\equiv1\bmod n$ for $n$ prime by Fermat's little theorem.)